# Stored procedure: get 3 values from a table and save them to another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE songs (_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, _artist TEXT, _name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE cafes (_id SERIAL, _ip TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE users (_id SERIAL UNIQUE, _imei TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE votes (_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, _cafe TEXT, _user INTEGER, _song INTEGER, _vote INTEGER);
```

I have a stored procedure that checks whether certain rows exist, and if they don't exist creates them.
Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(user_imei text, cafe_ip text, song_artist text, song_name text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE 
id_cafe INTEGER;
id_user INTEGER;
id_song INTEGER;
temp_row RECORD;
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT _id FROM users WHERE _imei = user_imei) THEN
    insert into users (_imei) values (user_imei);
END IF;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT _id FROM cafes WHERE _ip = cafe_ip) THEN
    insert into cafes (_ip) values (cafe_ip);
END IF;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT _artist FROM songs WHERE _artist = song_artist AND _name = song_name) THEN
    insert into songs (_artist, _name) values (song_artist, song_name);
END IF;    

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After all that I want to insert a new row into table `vote`, where:

_cafe = cafes._id
_song = songs._id
_user = users._id

Can anybody help to me?

Comment: So you want the `_id` values from those three tables that match the function's parameters and you want to create them if needed, correct? Are there any uniqueness constraints on the `users._imei`, `cafes.cafe_ip`, or `(_artist.song_artist, _artists.song_name)`?

Comment: Why do you have `_cafe TEXT` and not `_cafe integer` in table `votes`?

Comment: About cafe  - you have right. It is integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few adjustments.

- `user` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), I use `usr` instead as column name.
- Assuming column `votes.cafe` is `integer`, not `text`.
- Removed the leading underscores from column names. That's a peculiar naming convention. I usually use that for variables in plpgsql functions, so they never conflicts with column names ..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(
    _user_imei text
   ,_cafe_ip text
   ,_song_artist text
   ,_song_name text) RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE 
   id_cafe integer;
   id_user integer;
   id_song integer;
BEGIN

-- user
SELECT INTO id_user  id FROM users WHERE imei = _user_imei;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO users (imei) VALUES (user_imei)
   RETURNING id INTO id_user;
END IF;

-- cafe
SELECT INTO id_cafe  id FROM cafes WHERE ip = _cafe_ip;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO cafes (ip) VALUES (cafe_ip)
   RETURNING id INTO id_cafe;
END IF;

-- song
SELECT INTO id_song  id FROM songs
WHERE artist = _song_artist AND name = _song_name;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO songs (artist, name) VALUES (_song_artist, _song_name)
   RETURNING id INTO id_song;
END IF;

INSERT INTO votes (cafe, usr, song)  -- What about column vote??
VALUES (id_cafe, id_user, id_song);  -- Assuming cafe is type integer

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```